# Yet another kind of query is too complex in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an app that's been in production for a few years, so we know the SQL it generates is generally valid, and in this case, importing the tables into SQL Server 2016 allows the same queries to be run there without issue. The actual query is much more involved (many more nesting levels and multi-JOIN subqueries) than the one I'm posting here, and it always runs except in the case that is revealed in this greatly simplified example. This simple one doesn't run even in the MS Access query window itself.

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT individual_tests.*
       ,(SELECT TOP 1 test_categories.id FROM test_categories INNER JOIN performance_categories ON performance_categories.test_category_id = test_categories.id 
              WHERE performance_categories.id = individual_tests.performance_category_id) AS UsedInWhere 
       , (SELECT TOP 1 standard_designations.inactive_flag
         FROM ((standard_designations
         INNER JOIN standard_designation_revision_levels  ON standard_designation_revision_levels.standard_designation_id = standard_designations.id)
         INNER JOIN individual_tests_standard_rev_levels  ON individual_tests_standard_rev_levels.standard_designation_revision_level_id = standard_designation_revision_levels.id)
         INNER JOIN individual_tests ON individual_tests.id = individual_tests_standard_rev_levels.individual_test_id
         ) AS UnusedResultAnyway
 FROM individual_tests_standard_rev_levels INNER JOIN
 individual_tests
 ON individual_tests.id = individual_tests_standard_rev_levels.individual_test_id
  ) AS individual_tests
WHERE  (UsedInWhere = 1);
```

There are various changes I can make to the query to cause it to run without error, but they defeat the purpose of it.

If I change the WHERE at the bottom to not refer to the results of either sub-query, it runs. If I simplify either of the sub-queries to be

```
(1) AS UsedInWhere
```

or

```
(1) AS UnusedResultAnyway
```

it all works fine. IOW, I don't have to simplify the sub-query that computes UsedInWhere to be able to use that value in the WHERE. Merely simplifying or removing the other sub-query makes the query work without the

> Query is too complex

error. In some cases, I've found that making a different query more complex by adding logically unnecessary nesting levels has made the error go away, but we don't want to rely on such things.

Is there something about my approach that is conceptually weak and should not be used even though SQL Server doesn't complain? Should I just accept that MS Access sometimes cannot handle SQL that is both valid and simple, and devise a work-around using something like an in-memory table I can populate in pieces instead of using one query?

Comment: This is not a very helpful comment, but MS Access is not an enterprise level database. I suggest you just migrate to SQL Server and be done with it.

Comment: I agree with you and this is the only Access app I deal with and I inherited it, and as a contractor from outside the very large client, I am not in position to push the issue.  That said, I have been surprised that after my work to improve this app, it supports dozens of simultaneous users and some pretty complex queries.  It's looking like my latest problem is simply a bug outside of my control, but I came here to get confirmation of that, or a suggestion of improved code so we can get more life out of this important app without another work-around.

Comment: Yes I hear you. I just make a habit of saying there is business risk and technical debt and that's the language they may understand. I'm not an MS Access expert, but yes all I can think of is to break it up into bits. You could also perhaps think about how you can somehow use this to do some kind of  partial migration to SQL Server

Comment: The shop is mainly Oracle and gets most of their development of backbone systems in Bangalore, so though this app I sort-of saved and it's become mission-critical and very hard to replace, that doesn't mean I can get them to do the sensible thing.  The people I deal with there agree with you, but there is the IT kingdom to deal with.

Comment: Access SQL is more forgiving then t-sql in a lot of cases. In t-sql you can't use alias columns in other expressions (a huge pain). In Access sql you can. So I can go (Owe - Paid) as Balance, and then go (Balance * taxrate) as OwedWthTaxes. You can't do his in SQL server, and you have to repeat the whole expression. So, Access SQL allows many things you can't do in t-sql. You can avoid the query too complex if you correctly write the sql in Access format without the query builder. So in many cases Access sql allows one to do lots of thigs that don't work in t-sql (and of course vis versa).

Comment: In this case, each of the individual parts of the SQL work in both T-SQL and Access, including the use of computed values as long as a nested SELECT is used to derive the value in the inner SELECT and then referenced in the outer SELECT.  I started doing this in both Access and T-SQL 20 years ago.  In the current case, there is something else wrong with Access and I cannot make sense of it based on the symptoms we see here.  Each sub-query works fine, yet the removal or simplification of one allows the other's value to be used in the WHERE, but this is not needed in T-SQL.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal  As Mike points out, the Access query optimizer has major problems with otherwise valid SQL that it tries to "simplify"/reorder internally that then causes it to fail.  I won't claim that any implementation is free of bugs, but definitely Access is poor in this regard. This isn't simply about particular nuances of what each dialect supports, rather the inability of Access to properly interpret and execute nested queries.  And if we're keeping points, other SQL engines allow aliases in the WHERE clause and Access does not.

Comment: To the very last question, the answer must definitely be "yes" if you need to continue using Access.  What other answer is there?  If Access does not support particular queries, then of course the only way around that is to craft a different solution using various techniques.  However, I might be able to rewrite your statement as a single working query, but first of all... Is the result of the TOP 1 queries arbitrary?  If you don't you have an ORDER BY clause, the results are not guaranteed to return any particular record.  Or can you guaranteed that there is only a single record for each?

Comment: It may not fix the "Query is too complex" error, but it would at least improve readability to use table aliases.  That is especially true if nested queries are referring to the same table as the outer query.  Make sure each uses a unique alias.  I would even guess this is partly what "confusing" access and making the query "too complex".  Manually add aliases and see if that immediately improves anything.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts, especially about using aliases with different names.  I will try that.  I had hoped that my other option would be to accept somebody's syntax or structure correction here, but I can also just use my less elegant work-around.  I left out the ORDER BY to make it simpler for demonstration, and yes, the order would often make a difference when TOP 1 is used, but not in this case.  With it there are missing, the reported error is the same.

Comment: Well, we are using sql server as the back end, so any possibility of creating a view or even a pass-though query here?

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal I copied the tables to SQL Server to confirm that the SQL is valid, but SQL Server is not a part of the production environment.  I have implemented a work-around, but I will continue to play with the problem and have an MS Access guru who will see if he can use its query builder to assemble a version that works, in hopes that we discover a pattern for which we can develop some rules about what to look for and how to proceed.

Comment: @CPerkins In theory, any subquery and be "flattened" to a JOIN, but it's often hard to wrap one's mind around a particular case, so that's why I didn't just automatically try that when a subquery is so much easier to conceptualize.  And since they always work in T-SQL and almost always in MS Access, it's hard to justify avoiding new ones and refactoring old ones.

Comment: @MikeV  I agree that would be much simpler, it's just that Access is not so consistent and so it often forces queries to be refactored.  I considered ways to rewrite the query you gave, but after realizing that the statement in the question is just a paired down example, I doubt it will be that helpful since it sounds like you already know certain techniques and your actual query.  And your situation is even more challenging if the SQL is being generated by a tool. I don't know a set of consistent rules that would fix all such queries.

Comment: sql server not being part of the Access solution NOW begs the question why introduce SQL server, MySQL, Oracle, Postgress or any other system into this mix and discussion? Microsoft had JET/Access long before they had ANY version of SQL server (sql version was purchased from Sybase  and forked). No heritage or linage between the two products and all products have their own sql quirks. So testing against Oracle or MySQL makes no more sense then testing against SQL server.

Comment: I suppose if you turn on ansi-92 features of the Access app then you have SOME hope, but the revelation that this app has nothing to do with sql server is a HUGE whopper. Why not test against Postgress then? And if you have not turned on ansi-92 in feature in the Access application, then this approach and discussion about sql sever REALLY begs the question where you going here?

Comment: Unless at the VERY lest you turned on ansi-92 in Access (but the application better have been designed from the ground up with that feature turned on, or tons of existing code will break. As noted, the simple use of Alias in expressions will work in Access, but not in sql server (unless ou introduce a messy CTE, or re-write as a sub query, and create the expressions at the top query - quite  a large change to TEST syntax here.

Comment: @AlbertDKallal The reason for mentioning SQL Server was limited to how this suggests the SQL can be considered to not be flawed in some conspicuous conceptual way, but this wouldn't be very meaningful except that I also described how the same SQL structure, and often the exact same queries, often work in MS Access too, but sometimes do not.

It was the inconsistency that had me looking for a pattern which could serve all MS Access users in the future.  I haven't found that pattern, yet.